# issues integrating local fonts in react

Tags: styled-components, vite, font-face

Hey so i am trying to include custom fonts that i have placed in `assets/fonts`.Also i am using this inside GlobalStyles. Whenever i try to import the file by using:
`import fontLight from "./assets/fonts/` react is not able to recognise the `.ttf` file.
I am using **VITE**.How to implement the font?

I tried replacing the fonts, there are no tutorials or step by step explanation on this. I do not think how we implement fonts in react-native is the same as vite.I tried using `const imgUrl = new URL("./assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf", import.meta.url).href` after going through the vite documentation still i am not sure why react is not recognising the file.